# how to append data with slide down

Tags: jquery

I want to display data with the slide down effect using jquery, how should I do it? here my code

```
function cart(idx, jml) {
  var jumlah = $("#" + jml).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "load_data.php",
    data: {
      id: idx,
      jumlah: jumlah
    },
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('#showcart').append(data).show('slow');
  });
}

<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
  <div id="showcart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#showcart').append(data).slideDown();` maybe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should hide first `<div id="showcart" style='display:none'>` your div before you append.
After you append then show or use slidedown.